# How to call a function every time user opens application

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call the function named update every time user taps my app's icon and open it. How would I do that? Which method fires that I can override whenever the app launches no matter is killed from background or user pressed the home button.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var labeltwo: UILabel!

    var NSDateDefalt = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var date : NSDate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") as? NSDate
        label.text = "\(date)"
        update()
    }


    @IBAction func buttona(sender: AnyObject) {
        date = NSDate()
        label.text = "\(date)"

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSDate(), forKey:"yourKey")
    }



    func update(){
        let now = NSDate()
        let seconds = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(date!)
        labeltwo.text = "\(seconds))"
    }

}
```

Update: I implemented in my App Delegate

```
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        ViewController().update()     
    }
```

Comment: You should call it from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if you want to call it when app is launch. If you want to call it when app comes in foreground from background mode then you should call it from `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: Link to the App Life Cycle - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: call your method from applicationWillEnterForeground method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to implement your logic in AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

        // first launch
        // this method is called only on first launch when app was closed / killed
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

        // app will enter in foreground
        // this method is called on first launch when app was closed / killed and every time app is reopened or change status from background to foreground (ex. mobile call)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

        // app becomes active
        // this method is called on first launch when app was closed / killed and every time app is reopened or change status from background to foreground (ex. mobile call)
    }
}
```

**Update**

As Paulw11 suggests, consider using applicationWillEnterForeground instead of applicationDidBecomeActive

Comment: `applicationWillEnterForeground` is probably a better choice than `applicationDidBecomeActive` - the application will become inactive/active when a system dialog such as the control center or a permission dialog is shown

Comment: Thanks very much for you help. do you know why when I implemented the method in the app delegate, var date : NSDate! The warning message: this value founds nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: You're declaring date as NSDate! so you must be sure that when you use this variable its value is not nil (maybe you forgot to set value previusly?). Otherwise declare date: NSDate? if it could be nil and add a '?' before method (ex: date?.compare(anotherDate)). Depends what you want to do.

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!( the excitement of solving a bug.^_^ )

Comment: actually applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) is not called when the app is first launched and was closed/killed before

Comment: @4bottiglie in the scenarios that you describe, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called instead. So put your refresh logic in both `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 9):

In `ViewController.swift` in `viewDidLoad()` write either of these in respective manner:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.update), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.update), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

(EDIT: update for Swift 3)

(EDIT: removed part of this post that was incorrect. iOS triggers these notifications automatically to any added observer, no need to add code to trigger them in the App Delegate)

Comment: This answer is now correct - the comments refer to an earlier version that was partially incorrect.

Comment: i am a beginner in iOS, but i can state that copy/paste the lines  => code no accepeted in XCode 11.5. bye

Answer (score 7):

In your AppDelegate.swift, there are `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

`applicationWillEnterForeground` is similar to `viewWillAppear` for your viewControllers as opposed to your app, while `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is similar to `viewDidLoad` for your app. For more information, check [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/)

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift 5** use this code

1. Add this line in `func viewDidLoad()`

   `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateView), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)`
2. Add This function

   @objc func updateView() {

   }

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification.

Comment: Will be called even when users open closes control center.

Comment: `applicationWillEnterForeground` is probably a better choice than `applicationDidBecomeActive` - the application will become inactive/active when a system dialog such as the control center or a permission dialog is shown

Answer (score 1):

When app in terminated stated and user tap on app icon so first method called is

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

and when app in background mode and come to foreground

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

so u can call Update() in both method.But when Method called by didFinishLaunchingWithOptions don't call in applicationWillEnterForeground.Because when app launch both methods are called and when app enter in foreground mode only WillEnterForeground method call.  This can be manage by bool flag